# python update mongodb find().forEach give a error

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to update stock status for products, in MongoDB Shell its working perfect, but when i use it in Pyhton its giving me a wird error and i not understand why its giving me it.

my Python code is her

```
db['product'].find({
  'store_uuid': store_uuid,
  'uuid': str(curr_content['Product'])
}).forEach(bson.Code("""
  function (product) {
    product.stock.in_store.forEach(function (store_stock) {
      if (store_stock.Store == {store}) {
        store_stock.New = {new};
        store_stock.Used = {used};
      }
    });

    db.product.save(product);
  }
""").format(new=int(curr_content['New']), used=int(curr_content['Used']), store=str(curr_content['Store']))
)
```

the problem i get is

> AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'forEach'

and i really have no idea why its coming, my MongoDB Shell code look like this in demo, and its working whitout eny problems.

```
db.getCollection('product').find({
  'store_uuid': 'c30525de-8e51-4e5e-aa2c-eae0e21c8cec',
  'uuid': '788091af-2af9-4cb3-b898-1cec0c02ffcb'
}).forEach(function (doc) {
  doc.stock.in_store.forEach(function (event) {
    if (event.Store === 'f20c425e-03cb-4560-a0dd-68ee2bacf783') {
      event.New=10;
      event.Used=10;
    }
  });

  db.collection.save(doc);
});
```

What i want is running direct as a function inside MongoDB and not do stuff in Python. hope sombody can help me with this issue.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate? its not the same i want to do, its to diffenct things?

Comment: I don't think you can use the forEach javascript function the same in Python. Likely you need to just write a normal Python for loop as the cursor object returned is an array.